# What is the role of the image path when debugging a crash dump with WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

Until now I always included the image path as part of the symbols path, so I had something like this:

```
Symbol search path is: srv*e:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine
```

But what is the correct approach?

1. Should I include the image path as part of the symbols path as I do today?
2. Should I pass it as the image path?
3. Both?

Comment: Yup, the path to the executable. I am wondering why does it have a dedicated path and whether I am losing anything by not using it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You have never seen minidumps? It is strange :)

Comment: @ussrhero: I meant I have never seen minidumps with the executable stripped. Nevermind. My comment is obsolete by my answer anyway

Comment: standard minidump does not contain any executable image. You can not to notice this fact because all standard binaries is uploaded to microsoft public symbol server.

Comment: the recommended ?? or documented way is to do cdb -y sympath -i imagepath -z dump file the recommended ?? / documented way to set sym path is to use the Envvar _NT_SYMBOL_PATH and / or _NT_ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH with srv* syntax pointing to a downstore  and adding your own symbols to that path using symstore or pdbcopy or binpalce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### .sympath

If your symbol path is

```
srv*e:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine
```

it means that

1. WinDbg will search for symbols in `e:\Symbols`. If found, use it from there.
2. if not found, it will look on the Microsoft symbol server, download symbols if available, store it in e:\Symbols and use it from there.
3. if not found, it will look in e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine. If found, use it from there.

What actually happens in your case is not clear, because we don't know how you store symbols. If you add them to e:\Symbols, e.g. using `symstore add` in a post build step, the symbols for your executable will be used from e:\Symbols and e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine is useless.

If you don't use `symstore` and your symbols are actually located in e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine, symbols are used from that location.

If symbol information is in the executable (an exe may contain the full path to a PDB), WinDbg will also try to load it from there. If the executable was not built on your machine, that might fail due to the different paths, so adding a path like e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine can make sense.

### .exepath

There's another case where the minidump file does not contain the executable itself in order to minimize the size, so WinDbg has a hard task disassembling etc.

I never had that case myself (mainly because I work with .NET a lot, which needs full memory anyway), but an example is given in the book "Memory Dump Analysis Anthology Collector's Edition" by Dmitry Vostokov:

```
1:kd> ub bfabc399
                ^ Unable to find valid previous instruction for 'ub bfabc399'

1:kd> uf driver!ProcessObject
No code found, aborting
```

which can be solved by setting the executable path with the `.exepath` command. WinDbg will then load the assembly itself (not necessarily the symbols) from that location.

Comment: So, as long as I analyze a .NET process dump I do not need to have a dedicated exepath set, right? The **e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine** contains both the *.exe, *.dll and *.pdb files relevant to the process. We do not use a symbol server.

Comment: @mark: right, you don't need `.exepath` in that case. And as long as the path to the PDB in the executable points to e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine, you also don't need the `.sympath`. You can try without it and if `lm m <exe>` says `private symbols`, things are fine

Comment: The exe does not reference PDBs in **e:\tmp\BackgroundJobEngine**. But I have my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You may need to .reload to get windbg to walk the image path picking up dlls before you can do a "uf <dll>!<symbol> successfully.